# Laravel where of Relationship from Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have easy relationships like this

Project Model:

```
public function milestones()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Milestone');
}
```

Milestone Model:

```
public function milestones()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Milestone');
}
```

Now I try to get Todo with id = 3. And it should only show Milestone where my Todo is inside. This is my solution at the moment (shows all Milestones inside project)

```
    $query = Project::whereHas('milestones',function($query) use ($UserId){
        $query->whereHas('todo', function ($query) use ($UserId){
            $query->where('id',3);
        });
    })->with('milestones.todo',function($query){
        $query->where('id',3);
    })
    ->get();
```

How do I limit milestones to that one, where todo with id 3 is inside?

Comment: Is the `milestones` relationship in `Milestone` model meant to be the `todo` relationship? Also, is your solution working correctly?

Comment: Yes sorry, of corse it is ment to be the todo. My solution is working fine, but as I told I get all milestones. And I just want this one todo id,3 is inside

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be explicit with your eager load:

```
$query = Project
    ::with('milestones', function ($query) use ($UserId) {
        $query
            ->with([
                'todos' => function ($query) use ($UserId) {
                    $query->where('id', $UserId);
                },
            ])
            ->whereHas('todos', function ($query) use ($UserId) {
                $query->where('id', $UserId);
            });
    })
    ->whereHas('milestones', function ($query) use ($UserId) {
        $query->whereHas('todo', function ($query) use ($UserId) {
            $query->where('id', $UserId);
        });
    })
    ->get()
```

Comment: Okay, I understand but it runs into "mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string